# Is it possible to inspect the values entered in the Adyen payment widget and run validations against those values? And give error states?

Tags: adyen

I'm looking to set my own validations on my Adyen payment module. Specifically I want to eliminate people's ability to insert incorrect characters in card holder name field (like emojis, etc).

Comment: By adyen payment widgett do you mean adyen drop-in? or adyen web components?

Answer (score 1):

You are able to customize the validation logic implementing one of the handlers

```
        onChange: (state, component) => {
           // triggered at every change
           console.error("onChange " + JSON.stringify(state.data));
        },
        onSubmit: (state, component) => {
           // triggered upon submit
           console.error("onSubmit " + JSON.stringify(state.data));
           // grab holderName 
           var holderName =  state.data.paymentMethod.holderName;
           // apply your validation...
           if(validationOk) {
             makePayment(state.data)
             // etc etc
           }
        }
```

Check [Web Dropin integration guide](https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/web-drop-in/integrated-before-5-0-0?tab=codeBlockpayments_request_component_8AezQ_JS_7#step-2-add-drop-in). Make sure to check which version you are using (to refer to the relevant documentation), however the workflow is similar.